# How to make the camera in Unity be able to see my character?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I'm creating a 2D project.

The Camera is a child of the character. This is the second camera. The main camera is able to see the whole thing. The only thing that the second camera shows is the blue background.

This picture shows the hierarchal and inspector of the Object:
[hierarchal and inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIv3U.jpg)

This picture shows the inspector of the second camera:
[Camera Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atXEJ.jpg)

This shows the position of camera:
[position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rCiZ.jpg)

I'm expecting a way to make the camera be able to see my character and the map.

Comment: tweak the `transform` of the child camera and find out where it can see the player

Comment: @Geeky Quentin It's actually already at the position. I've edit the question to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the camera position ... It's child for the character and I see it's z is 0 which that mean it is in the same depth of 2D Layer .. so you have to move it back.. you can change the view to 3D mode to see it more clearly ..
Conculotion : switch to 3D mode and change the Z position in the camera .
Hope it help..

Better solution : make a script to get the transform of the character and then set the camera to that position (((( with offset )))

```
public Transform character;
public Vector3 offset;
void Update(){
    transform.position = character.position+offset;
}
```

Put Script like this in the camera and get it out from the character and set the offset for something like (0,0,-2) and try diffrent z values untill get you want

Comment: a) you can simply change the Z position via the Inspector.. no need to switch to 3D mode at all ^^ .. b) why is that script way the better solution? It adds some unnecessary work every frame while the nesting way just works directly

Comment: a) XD yes you can do that from theinspector :) but I wanted him to see the the all scene to better understan why he need to move the Zposition ___ b) if the camera is a chield for the Player... what will happen when the player jump ? the camera will move up with him and this annoying .. controlling with script will give  more flixable and control option :) and offcourse you righ if the player just move tigh and left will be enough to fix it in the inspector ^^ thanks for your comment

Comment: Or maybe it is intended that the camera jumps with the player maintaining the player **always** centered in the screen e.g.